# When I append to a list, it appends two numbers for some reason

Tags: python, list, append, max

I am doing Leetcode 198. House Robber using a DP approach. My code passes the test case of

```
nums = [1,2,3,1]
```

but fails

```
nums = [2,7,9,3,1]
```

I noticed, using print statements, that it was appending 2 numbers when i == 1 for some reason.
my sum list is [2] when i == 1. Then I calculate the max of nums[0] and nums[1] which is 7. I append the 7 to the sums list. I check with a print statement. It is now [2, 5, 7]. Where is the 5 coming from and what am I doing wrong?

```
class Solution:
    def rob(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:

        sum = []
      
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return nums[0]
        if len(nums) == 2:
            return max(nums)
      
        
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if i == 0:
                sum.append(nums[i])
               
            if i == 1:
                sum.append(max(nums[i], nums[i - 1]))
            else:
                sum.append(max(nums[i] + nums[i - 2], nums[i - 1]))
              
    
        return max(sum[len(sum) - 1], sum[len(sum) - 2])
```

Comment: 5 comes from the second `if` in the loop when `i=0`. Change `if` to `elif` (assuming it is what you actually want to do).

Comment: Hint: what is `nums[0] + nums[-2]`?

Answer (score 1):

In your else statement when i=1:

```
sum.append(max(nums[i] + nums[i - 2], nums[i - 1]))
```

should be replaced by

```
sum.append(max(nums[i] + sum[i - 2], sum[i - 1]))
```

this is because both the statements are executed and its wrong.